# Ordering the SQL query in a particular order

Tags: php, sql, sql-order-by

Say i have a table `Guest` and it has column `g_id` : values 1 to 10.

Now i want the query to return me the g_id's neither in ascending order nor in descending..
but i want the 4th then 3rd and then 5th entry, in this particular order.
Also i want just the 4th 3rd and 5th entry.

say my entries have an id and a name . ;i.e. my table Guest has these two tables.
Now my table is as following.

```
1 A
2 B
3 C
4 D
5 E
6 F
7 G
8 H
9 I
10 J
```

Now i want just the entry with 4th 3rd and 5th `g_id`, and in this particular order.

How do i write the SQL query?
Thanks.

Select * from Guest ***_*__*_*__*_*____**???

Kindly fill in the gaps.

Comment: So, where should g_id value 1,2,6,7,8,9 and 10 fit in this search order?

Comment: @Brian Hoover  edits..  only id's 3 4 5 are needed.

Comment: This is hard to understand without an example.

Comment: use this: WHERE  g_id IN (3, 4, 5)

Comment: I think all of these answers so far have missed the fact that the OP does not want g_ids 4,3,5, but rather the 4th, 3rd, and 5th entries of a random distribution of the g_id column, this might be g_ids (1, 10, 3)

Comment: by 4, 3, 5... do you mean `g_id` values?

Comment: @Nonym  yeah.. edited once again.. i want the entry with id= 4 & 3 & 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `CASE` statement in your `ORDER BY` to use a fake column to sort on and a `WHERE IN` clause to only return the values you need.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   Guest
WHERE  g_id IN (3, 4, 5)
ORDER BY
       CASE WHEN g_id = 4 THEN 1
            WHEN g_id = 3 THEN 2
            WHEN g_id = 5 THEN 3
       END
```

Answer (score 2):

What is the order that deteremines whether something is 4th, 3rd or 5th? Without an `ORDER BY` clause, the data is returned in an indeterminate order by SQL. You cannot rely on the order that rows are entered or stored in the database table itself.

You can hard-code what you are asking like this:

```
select *
from Guest
order by case 
    when g_id = 4 then 1
    when g_id = 3 then 2
    when g_id = 5 then 3
    else 4
end
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is the `case` statement:

```
select g_id from (
    select g_id, case g_id
       when 4 then 1
       when 3 then 2
       when 5 then 3
       else 0
    end virtcol
    where virtcol != 0
    order by virtcol
);
```

Comment: also i want just these three entries.. not all!  how do i fit that into this.?

Comment: See edit of post... You could have said that from the start ;)

Comment: what is a virtcol??
also wont i need to do where g_id = 4 && g_id=3 && g_id=5.

Comment: It is just a name for the `case ... end` statement, it could have been `herpies`, `snafu`...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how set your ordering will be, but you can order by specifics:

```
ORDER BY
   g_id = 4 DESC,
   g_id = 3 DESC,
   g_id = 5 DESC
```

You may be better off selecting the entries as they are and doing something like this in your php code:

```
$order = array('4 ', '3 ', '5 ');
$data = array();
while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
   $data["$row->g_id "] = $row;
}
$data = array_merge(array_flip($order), $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the answer mostly depends on the DBMS you are working on.

In Oracle the query below, even though inefficient, should work

```
select * from 
    (select * , rownum as order from guest order by id asc ) b 
where b.order = 4
UNION
select * from 
    (select * , rownum as order from guest order by id asc ) b 
where b.order = 3
UNION
select * from 
    (select * , rownum as order from guest order by id asc ) b 
where b.order = 5
```

Not sure if something of more efficient is possible with a simple query,
i would use the monster above only and only if the table you are querying is very small.

You also have another option if the table is big and you have to extract only the first rows. In the case you described, I would retrieve the first 5 rows and then programmatically I would extract the rows in position 4,3,5.

you can extract the first 5 rows with this query in oracle

```
select * from guest order by id asc where rownum < 6
```

Answer (score 0):

This query will get you the 3rd, 5th, and 4th items (`limit 2, 1` means "retrieve starting with 3rd item, with total number retrieved = 1 records)

```
(select g_id from Guest limit 2,1)
UNION (select g_id from Guest limit 4,1
UNION (select g_id from Guest limit 3,1)
```